# HP blade server: How many connection can be made between HP new gen 8 blades and an interconnect

Tags: hp, blade-server

I am building a virtualized network on an HP C3000 with 460c Gen 8 blades and 2 HP L3 switch interconnects.  I was advised to by a 1Gb 4-port 366M Mezzanine Adapter.  That provides me 6 ethernet connections to each blade.     I have been told that you can only make 2 connections to from each blade to each interconnect, but since I have to interconnectes and 6 ports I hope someone can tell me if I can make 3 connections from each server to each interconnect.   I looking for the actual - thanks Dave

Comment: I'm sure chopper will chime in on hardware specifics, but I suggest you plan to use an EVEN number of uplinks.

Comment: If you aren't sure what kind of blades, chassis, and interconnect you want; make sure you talk with someone who knows this stuff before ordering. 1. The C3000 usually costs more than a C7000 (economics of scale reasons), and the C3k has less features. 2. The L3 Switch is only a little cheaper than the Flex10, and the latter has a lot more features. 3. The BL490 is sometimes cheaper than the BL460, depends on your configuration and needs.. 4. Last generation equipment is dirt cheap, consider G7 servers. 5. If you're getting quoted more than 2/3 of list price you're getting ripped off (probably)

Comment: My apologies if this comes across as offensive, but the configuration you're asking about screams of you not knowing what you're buying. If you have some time in the morning on a weekday, drop me a comment and I'll invite you to chat (since you don't have enough rep yet), we've got several people who know a lot about blade servers (even I am just getting started really, and these others put my knowledge to shame). They also know what the prices *should be*...

Comment: How many blades are you planning to purchase? If you're not planning to completely fill out this chassis, it's very likely traditional rackmount servers are a better fit for you (unless you just really hate cables).

Answer (score 1):

Or I'll make a better attempt to answer your question here, someone can correct me though because perhaps my HP specific knowledge is limited.

Typically a blade server will have onboard connections to the first two interconnect slots. So lets say there are two onboard NICs, you will get one connection to each of those two interconnect modules you have mentioned.

If you need more than what is available onboard, then you need to purchase mezzanine cards. However, those cards tend to connect that blade to DIFFERENT interconnect modules. I suggest you talk to a knowledgeable HP pre-sales engineer to make sure you understand exactly what you need to meet your requirements.

Here's just an example from an HP guide:

[image]

Comment: +1 But, the BL460c comes with a Dual Port 10Gb NIC (there are 3 different types, but they all work the same for this explanation), where one of each of the ports is connected to each interconnect 1 & 2. The Mezzanine cards will only connect to Interconnects 3 & 4, as you have pictured. So there's no point in mezz cards if there are no Interconnects in Bays 3 & 4.